# How to invalidate cache inside a proxy in WSO2 ESB 6.6.0

Tags: java, caching, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I would  like to know how can I invalidate the cache created by the Cache Mediator just by calling a proxy.
According to the [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Cache+Mediator)  we can do that by using a JMX Monitoring tool. But we do not want to do something like this.

So I've made a custom mediator

```
import javax.cache.CacheException;
import javax.cache.Caching;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

public class CacheInvalidateMediator extends AbstractMediator
{
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CacheInvalidateMediator.class);

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext synCtx)
    {
        try
        {
            Caching.getCacheManager("cacheManager").getCache("mediatorCache").removeAll();
            log.info("Total mediator cache has been invalidated.");
        }
        catch(CacheException cacheException)
        {
            throw new CacheException("Error occurred while invalidating mediator cache. " + cacheException);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

It works for EI 6.2.0 but now for EI 6.6.0 it is deprecated and I can't figure how to do the same thing now. Do you have any idea ?

Regards.

**EDIT**

I tried to do an iteration on getCaches(). It seems that I do not have the right name for the cache manager.

```
public class CacheInvalidateMediator extends AbstractMediator { 
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CacheInvalidateMediator.class);


    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
        try {
            log.info("JAVA REMOVING CACHE...");
            log.info(Caching.getCacheManager("cacheManager"));
            log.info(Caching.getCacheManager("cache"));
            Iterable<Cache<?, ?>> iterable1 = Caching.getCacheManagerFactory().getCacheManager("__default__").getCaches();
            log.info("iterate :");
            for(Cache<?, ?> cache : iterable1) {
                log.info("cache : "+cache.getName());
                cache.removeAll();
            }



            Iterable<Cache<?, ?>> iterable2 = Caching.getCacheManagerFactory().getCacheManager("cache").getCaches();
            log.info("iterate :");
            for(Cache<?, ?> cache : iterable2) {
                log.info("cache : "+cache.getName());
                cache.removeAll();
            }

            log.info("Total mediator cache has been invalidated.");

            log.info("JAVA CACHE INVALIDATE");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(e.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Based on [github project](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-mediation/blob/master/components/mediators/cache/org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/mediator/cache/CachingConstants.java), I've tried to use some constants, but anything seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The caching implementation was totally rewritten in the later releases. Hence using javax CacheManager to clear the cache would not work in EI 6.6.0. But still there is a MBean implementation to invalidate the cache. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-mediation/blob/master/components/mediators/cache/org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/mediator/cache/MediatorCacheInvalidator.java

You should try out an implementation to invoke this MBean to invalidate the cache.

Comment: I agree with this method (implement MBean), but i can't figure out how MBean create its CacheManager object with every data inside. It is not a problem for tenantDomain or tenantId (if I can get them, it's cool, but there is a workaround) or messageContext (I get it in my mediator declaration)